# Importing features from MIF-file without their prefiltering

Tags: qgis, import, mif

I wanted to import a MIF layer into QGIS and found out in the attribute table that it was already *"prefiltered"*, meaning that from a total of 7,000 features it was filtered to around 60.

I didn't find an option to deselect the filter. I then attempted to safe the layer as Shape or GeoPackage and reload it, but it didn't work.

Does someone know the reason for it and how to fix it? I have never had these problems with QGIS before.